# Overshoot Before Transition

Tags: current-source, linear, non-linear, circuits

First of all, a little bit of context: I'm designing a single-supply Howland current source using the OPA357 (rail-to-rail 200MHz OPAMP) to delivery 100uA of AC current up to 1MHz. In one of my attempts, I obtained with the following circuit:

[image: Howland Source]

As I was designing using frequency domain, I got this response using PSPICE:

[image: Modulus: Blue Line. Phase: Red Line]

Yes, a nasty peak in 100 MHz. Worried about my waveforms, I did transient analysis using square wave signal (1MHz), and I noticed overshoot spikes that happens before transition:

[image: Inside the red circles]

Well, I'm familiar with frequency peaks resulting in overshoots, but I'm certainly not with overshoots happening before transitions. After further investigations, I noticed that this extra current is demanded by the positive input of the OPAMP (when I isolated this input with an ideal buffer, the peaks disappeared).

I solved the problem increasing the size of the resistors, but I'm still not able to understand the behaviour. I don't recall of any conditions that make linear systems behave this way, so I guess that is a non-linear effect of the OPAMP input stage (is a rail-to-rail stage, after all). Anyway, can someone explain to me in which conditions this kind of "pre-transition overshoot" can happen? Is this a linear behaviour? Can you point out how this is happening in my circuit?

Best regards

Comment: Well, after more research, I've found something that is very similar to what is happening: non-minimun phase response, meaning zeros in the right-plane domain. I will need to take the transfer function of the system (now including the positive input capacitance) to search for this fellas, in order to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: Do not forget your probe capacitance. Ringing and overshoot are a sign of a miss-match in the signal path. Can your 4.7 pF cap be adjusted? Why the large value 10 K resistor in the output? Usually at high-frequencies output impedance is kept to 50 to 75 ohms.

Comment: Sparky256 Yes, the probe parasitics are problematic in high frequency, however the results are from simulations, therefore no probe issues. The resistor value sets the transconductance of the Howland source, it's not for impedance matching.

Comment: Note that a 'perfect' out come may not be possible over such a wide range. The software is seeing a phase shift at 100 MHZ. Real-world conditions could be much worse.

Answer (score 1):

The OPA357 has a bandwidth of a bit less than 100 MHz when used in an inverting configuration as per your 2nd op-amp. Look at the top right picture on page 5 of the data sheet. Also note that the GBW product is stated at 100 MHz and if you look at the open-loop gain diagram on the bottom right of page 7 it clearly indictaes 100 MHz is unity gain.

You cannot expect a Howland current source to behave with dignity at 100 MHz if you use this op-amp.

I think the under-shoot situation you got is a little difficult to get to the bottom of because you only show the output waveform in your question and there is nothing to indicate the input waveform and what it might be doing. Both superimposed on the same graph would help.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening (and I must qualify this answer by pointing out that I am a bit rusty when it comes to linear circuits with feedback loops) is that, near the 100MHz mark the phase of the feedback signal is shifted near 180 degrees, which means that you have a positive feedback, and hence a local maximum in the transfer curve. You say you solved the issue by increasing the size of the resistors - well, depending on which resistors you increased, that would also be consistent with removing the positive feedback loop at a given frequency. The thing is, by increasing a specific resistor's value you may have pushed the point where the feedback signal's phase is inverted, to a frequency where the intensity of the feedback signal is small enough to not cause issues.

Now to the question of why would positive feedback cause the sort of strange transients you see in the response to a square wave, I don't know the exact answer, but I do remember seeing "ringing" distortion of square signals in circuits with positive feedback. This ringing is more prominent the higher the quality factor Q of the circuit.

Comment: In any case, I like the question and wish there were more like this. +1

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Yes, the frequency peaking is probably due to poor phase margin of the circuit, and I tried to reduce this with that capacitor in the negative feedback. I was not in the mood for calculations, so the amount of compensation was not correct (hence the ugly frequency response). But that strange overshoot really got my attention, so even though I solved the problem, I needed to ask.